# Skype automatically logs in on new computer

Tags: windows-10, skype

I have a relatively new computer with Windows 10, and some time ago I suddenly got a skype message. I have never installed Skype on this computer, but I guess it comes with Windows. Stranger, I have only ever used this skype account on my work computer, I can't recall ever logging in on my home computer.

Is there some magic autologin feature in Skype (if so, how does it work), or is my memory just bad?

Comment: Do you use in work and home the same MS account to sign in Windows 10?

Comment: No. But I have signed in to my webmail on both computers. My skype login is my gmail address.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Windows 10 comes with a 'Skype Preview' app bundled on the Anniversary Update, you probably got it on the automatic updates... and it logs in automatically to your account after it is installed.

To stop this, you can open the Skype Preview app from the Start Menu and log off from there manually, or simply uninstall the app by right clicking on it and selecting 'Uninstall'.

Comment: It's not the fact that skype is installed that is what puzzles me, it's why I'm logged in when I can't remember ever doing so. I'm using my gmail, and not my windows account for my skype login.